# RTI DDS creating own data types

Tags: data-distribution-service

I am working on a .Net example where I define my own data type using RTI Connext DDS.

Instead of creating the application from the beginning, I got help from the source code of the hello_world_xml_dynamic example in rti_workspace directory. I have made several changes to the USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml file to create my own data type and changes its name to MY_PROFILES.xml

But when I compile the application and run it from the command line, I get the following error:

```
DDS_DomainParticipantFactory_create_participant_from_config_w_paramsI:ERROR: Profile library 'MyParticipantLibrary::PublicationParticipant' not found
! Unable to create DDS domain participant
```

**The line of code that catching the error**:

```
if (this.participant == null)
{
this.participant = DDS.DomainParticipantFactory.get_instance().
create_participant_from_config(
"MyParticipantLibrary::PublicationParticipant");
if (this.participant == null)
{
Console.Error.WriteLine("! Unable to create DDS domain participant");
return;
}
}
```

**this is the configuration file MY_PROFILES.xml :**

```
<!--
RTI Data Distribution Service Deployment
-->
<dds xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://community.rti.com/schema/6.0.1/rti_dds_profiles.xsd">

    <!-- Qos Library -->
    <qos_library name="qosLibrary">
        <qos_profile name="DefaultProfile">
        </qos_profile>
    </qos_library>

    <!-- types -->
    <types>  
        <struct name="FlightData">
            <member name="Latitude"  type="double"/>
            <member name="Longitude" type="double"/>
            <member name="Altitude"   type="double"/>
        </struct>
    </types>

    <!-- Domain Library -->
    <domain_library name="MyDomainLibrary" >

        <domain name="FlightDataDomain" domain_id="0">
            <register_type name="FlightDataType"
                           type_ref="FlightData" />
            <topic name="FlightDataTopic"
                   register_type_ref="FlightDataType">
                <topic_qos name="FlightData_qos"
                           base_name="qosLibrary::DefaultProfile"/>
            </topic>
        </domain>
    </domain_library>

    <!-- Participant library -->
    <domain_participant_library name="MyParticipantLibrary">

        <domain_participant name="PublicationParticipant"
                            domain_ref="MyDomainLibrary::FlightDataDomain">
            <publisher name="MyPublisher">
                <data_writer name="FlightDataWriter"
                             topic_ref="FlightDataTopic"/>
            </publisher>
        </domain_participant>

        <domain_participant name="SubscriptionParticipant"
                            domain_ref="MyDomainLibrary::FlightDataDomain">
            <subscriber name="MySubscriber">
                <data_reader name="FlightDataReader"
                             topic_ref="FlightDataTopic">
                    <datareader_qos name="FlightData_reader_qos"
                                    base_name="qosLibrary::DefaultProfile"/>
                </data_reader>
            </subscriber>
        </domain_participant>

    </domain_participant_library>

</dds>
```

where am i making a mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML file looks correct. From the 'not found' error message, it seems that you may not have taken the right steps to instruct your application to load that profiles-file `MY_PROFILES.xml` to actually learn about your desired Participant. You can easily verify that this is the case by introducing an error in your XML file (for example by incorrectly renaming one tag) and rerun your application. If it does not complain about the syntax or schema of the XML, then your file did not get loaded and this hypothesis is correct.

*If* that turns out to be your problem indeed, then you have several options to fix that. They are listed in the User's Manual section [18.5 How to Load XML-Specified QoS Settings](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/6.0.1/doc/manuals/connext_dds/html_files/RTI_ConnextDDS_CoreLibraries_UsersManual/index.htm#UsersManual/How_to_Load_XML_Specified_QoS_Settings.htm#xmlconfiguration_1275484337_316960%3FTocPath%3DPart%25203%253A%2520Advanced%2520Concepts%7C18.%2520Configuring%2520QoS%2520with%2520XML%7C18.5%2520How%2520to%2520Load%2520XML-Specified%2520QoS%2520Settings%7C_____0).

Comment: Although I made a few changes in the configuration file, I did not receive any different error warnings and realized that my configuration file was not detected by DDS. 
I changed the name of my file to "USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml" and DDS automatically detected it. Thanks for the link Reiner.

Comment: Glad to help. In the long run, it may be better to give your XML file a unique name and use one of the documented mechanisms to point to that file. That way, you know for sure which file is being used (as opposed to implicitly relying on the file named `USER_QOS_PROFILES.xml` being present in the right location).